# How do you deal with PT9's fake delay compensation and Aux Delays when sound designing or mixing

Tags: troubleshooting, pro-tools-9

PT 9's Delay Compensation is a joke.  It doesn't even work.  Maybe it's just my system.  So since the ADC is not working, every time you use an AUX you get at least an 8 sample delay.

Even with the channels empty I'm getting this nightmare!!!

Try effects processing a voice, you really notice it then.

The channels can even be empty and when you send thru multiple aux's (daisy chain )  the delay is increased maybe squared. ( 8x8 )

Comment: can't you offset the delay in the mix window's 'Delay Compensation'?

Comment: No thats an HD thing

Comment: @ChrisSound - you sure about that? I have it and I'm not on HD - but I do have the Production Tool Kit installed... have you seen this? http://protools.dudesnetwork.com/2011/06/02/delay-compensation-explained-part-2-of-2/ 

Comment: Checking into this, thanks redsonic.  I do not have PT Kit.


Answer (score 1):

There's a work-around; it's kind of a pain, but so's the latency...

First, make a safety copy of all of your tracks as alternate playlists, so you can go back if need be. Then Option+Command-Click (or Alt+Control-Click) on the channel's vol/peak/delay display so you know how many ms the delay is. Then nudge your track forward in time by that number of milliseconds.

Like I said, a pain. But it will help with the plug-in delay on audio channels. AUX delays may be measurable in the same way; I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Chris,

I'm curious what type of plug-ins you are using in your aux channels?
They might be the source of the delay/latency...

oh and did you ask this question on avid's forum/DUC?

Comment: Even with the channels empty I'm getting this nightmare!!!

Try effects processing a voice, you really notice it then.

Comment: Yes I have posted on DUC.  Seems that it is a common problem?  No fix...?

Comment: Hi Chris, I've been checking on my system and i don't have this delay at all (only with plugin's on aux, but that's normal). What are your settings in the playback engine? Can you upload a session without audio which has this issue? I'm really curious, why i don't have the issue.

Comment: Problem fixed I think.  Thanks to RedSonic's post about the link for how delay comp works, it seems to be fixed.  If it pops up again, I'll post.  Thanks for the help.


Comment: @ChrisSound - glad I could help :)